# Difference between Image Analysis Window and other associated tools?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, image-analysis

I've been unable to find some concrete ESRI documentation on this.

What are the differences between the Image Analysis Window tools and the corresponding tools in other toolboxes? How come the Image Analysis is *so much* faster?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and expand on what you mean?  can you give examples of how you say that window is so much faster?  What tools/functions are you running and corresponding slower tools elsewhere?

Comment: Preferably just ask about one specific aspect of one tool that you believe to be slower.

Comment: @moosology https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 6):

The [Image Analysis Window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/image-analysis-window-processing-section.htm) uses raster functions which are applied on the fly and in memory. This is so much quicker as the functions process only the (resampled) pixels that are on the screen.

The ArcGIS Desktop help doesn't document this well, but it is discussed in the [raster functions GitHub page](https://github.com/Esri/raster-functions):

> Raster functions are lightweight and process only the pixels visible on your screen, in memory, without creating intermediate files. They are powerful because you can chain them together and apply them on huge rasters and mosaics on the fly.

and in the [ArcGIS Pro Help](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/get-started-with-image-and-raster-processing.htm):

> Traditionally, you would take the red and near infrared bands and
>   create a new dataset that has that equation calculated on every pixel.
>   When you use functions to apply the NDVI function to a dataset, the
>   image draws on your screen and the equation is applied at the same
>   time. It processes only the pixels that are on the screen. As you zoom
>   in and pan around, the equation is applied only to the pixels
>   on-screen. This significantly decreases the processing time and avoids
>   creating intermediate files. Rather than saving the output, you save
>   the processing information, which creates a virtual layer.